# Loop to create a new collection

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am going through Python's official tutorial and in the loop section, it proposes two types of strategies for changing dictionaries (which I found tricky as a novice, as I could sometimes get index out of bound errors for this type of thing). 1. Create a copy, and 2. Create a new collection.

Below are the codes provided by Python Official web (users list are added by me).

```
def try_loop_iterate_copy():

    users = {'amy': 'inactive', 'lily': 'active', 'poppy': 'active'}
    #Strategy:  Iterate over a copy
    for user, status in users.copy().items():
        if status == 'inactive':
            del users[user]
    print(users)
```

result:

```py
{'lily': 'active', 'poppy': 'active'}
```

```
def try_loop_new_collection():

    users = {'amy': 'inactive', 'lily': 'active', 'poppy': 'active'}
    # Strategy:  Create a new collection
    active_users = {}
    for user, status in users.items():
        if status == 'active':
            active_users[user] = status
    print(active_users)
```

result:

```
{'lily': 'active', 'poppy': 'active'}
```

I got the same result running both, however I cannot get my head around why `active_users[user] = status` works in the way it does. Why is it assigning status to `active_users[user]`, and managing to get the full list of active users and their status in a new list ? I'd appreciate a kind explanation for the novice.

Comment: "changing list"? or "changing dictionaries"? Also what don't you get about how `active_users[user] = status` works? It's similar to spending an item to a list. Just in this case it will appendke/value

Comment: Can you elaborate which part you did not get it?

Comment: The simpler (and more "Pythonic" IMO) way to do this is: `users = {user: status for user, status in users.items() if status != 'inactive'}`

Comment: That's really neat thanks Samwise!

Answer (score 3):

The first one **changes** the dictionary **size** during iteration, hence the need to iterate on a copy.

The second one populates (modify would also work) a dictionary on which it is not iterating.

The rule of thumb is: if you iterate on a sequence/mutable mapping, **do not modify it's size during iteration**.

Answer (score 2):

```
active_users[user] = status
```

This line updates the dict entry with the key `user`.  If the entry exists (not the case you have), it overwrites the old value with the new one, just like any variable.  Since the key does *not* yet exist in the dict, this line adds a new entry, with key `user` and value `status`.

One entry at a time, that loop copies information from the old dict to the new one.

Try adding a couple of useful `print` statements to the code, and watch it work:

```
users = {'amy': 'inactive', 'lily': 'active', 'poppy': 'active'}
# Strategy:  Create a new collection
active_users = {}
for user, status in users.items():
    print('\n', user, status)
    if status == 'active':
        active_users[user] = status
    print(active_users)
```

Result:

```
 amy inactive
{}

 lily active
{'lily': 'active'}

 poppy active
{'lily': 'active', 'poppy': 'active'}
```

Comment: Your answer was super helpful thank you!!